# Dev tools for media query break points?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have been coding responsive designs and have been looking at responsiveness on the websites that I visit.

I was wondering whether there is any way I can take a look at what width the site has set break point using the dev-tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes simply use the browsers developer **(F12)** tools and look at the media queries in css. Provided this is where they have specified thier breaks.

Look at the `@media` rules in the stylesheet editor.

**Firefox example**

[image]